# How to understand the storage process in solidity?

Tags: storage

What is the meaning of :
require(newKittenId == uint256(uint32(newKittenId)));

**Edit:**

Complete relevant code:

```
uint256 newKittenId = kitties.push(_kitty) - 1;

// It's probably never going to happen, 4 billion cats is A LOT, but
// let's just be 100% sure we never let this happen.
require(newKittenId == uint256(uint32(newKittenId)));
```

Comment: This question is not related to ERC-721. It is a Kitties-specific question. Tags edited.

Answer (score 3):

Ensuring that `newKittenId < 2 ** 32`.

This can also be achieved simply by declaring `newKittenId` as `uint32`.

A possible reason for declaring it as `uint256` is performance optimization.

**Edit:**

Following your edit, it is clear why `newKittenId` was declared `uint256`, as `push` returns the length of the array, whose type is `uint256`. Yet the author wanted to ensure that this actual length never reaches `2 ** 32` (revert the operation upon such attempt).

Comment: Declaring `newKittenId` as a `uint32` would not allow you to detect this problem. But `require(newKittenId < 2**32);` seems like a fine solution. (Again, perhaps there was some type of optimization happening?)

Comment: `.push` returns a `uint256`. Casting to a `uint32` could potentially cause two kittens to have the same id, which is what is being avoided here.

Comment: @TjadenHess: There was no `push` in the question at the time I answered it, just a single `require` expression.

Comment: @smarx: The assignment `uint256 newKittenId = kitties.push(_kitty) - 1` wasn't in the question when I answered it. Only the `require` expression at the top of the question was there, and this dude was asking what it meant, so I just took my best guess to explain it.

Comment: @goodvibration The answer is good; I'm just objecting to the line "This can also be achieved simply by declaring `newKittenId` as `uint32`." That line would not do what the `require` is doing.

Comment: (I'd recommend just editing that out.)

Comment: @smarx: I disagree. `uint32 newKittenId` ==> `newKittenId == uint256(uint32(newKittenId)`. So using the LHS would necessarily imply the RHS. Can you please explain why you think otherwise?

Comment: If you use `uint32 newKittenId = ...`, then when the array length reaches 2**32,  `newKittenId == 0`. The point of the `require` is to revert the transaction when this occurs, but with your code, the transaction would succeed but would create a duplicate ID.

Comment: @smarx: Like I said, when I wrote this, there was only a single line in the question: "What is the meaning of : require(newKittenId == uint256(uint32(newKittenId)));". So I did my best in guessing why would anyone use this expression instead of simply declaring the variable as `uint32`, and explained that the `require` could be reduced to declaring the variable as such.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That said, your suggestion _never_ did the same thing as a `require` statement. (Notably, it never reverts.) And regardless, now that the question has been clarified, do you agree that the line in question _isn't_ a workable alternative? If so, would you please delete it?

Comment: @smarx: I did so, nevertheless, in my initial answer I stated that the sole purpose of such `require` is "Ensuring that `newKittenId < 2 ** 32`". This is true in the sense that this is the purpose of this statement. You could argue that the purpose is to revert the operation, but that's just a technical notion IMO. Then I stated that "This can also be achieved simply by declaring `newKittenId` as `uint32`". Again, ensuring the above could also be achieved by declaring the variable as such, so this statement also holds.

Comment: It seems like you're arguing that `x %= 10` has the same "purpose" as `require(x < 10)`. I hope the comment thread here will help steer people clear of danger.

Comment: @goodvibration Can u please tell me what does this return? uint256 newKittenId = kitties.push(_kitty) - 1. Doesnt .push() add an element to the array? What is the value from which we are subtracting 1?

Comment: @GauravKumar: `kitties.push(_kitty)` returns the length of the `kitties` array after an element was added to it. Hence `kitties.push(_kitty) - 1` returns the length of the `kitties` array before an element was added to it.